# Reset values every day with mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, react-native

I need to clean every day a values on mongo db

That´s like ---> Reset every day when its 00AM
AND
Reset every end of month

```js
const totalOfDay = 123
const totalOfMonth = 12344
```

every day reset the totalDay, and every end of month reset totalMonth

I did this on my front-end, but with the app close this dont work, and the server will be online everytime, so that´s (I THINK) more easier

Comment: Have you checked out [scheduled trigger](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/triggers/#scheduled-triggers)?